# python PIL chops top of my draw.text

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am using python and PIL to draw some text. I stumbled upon certain tutorial 'cause I needed some guides on how to center text within certain bounds:

the code works but it has some strange behavior. It eats the top of string. Here's how it should like http://img855.imageshack.us/img855/9292/qttempya4744.png

and here's how it looks http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/8541/outn.jpg

here's my code :

```
import os
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont, Image
def draw_text(text, size, fill=None):
    font = ImageFont.truetype('C:\exl.ttf', 30)
    size = font.getsize(text)# Returns the width and height of the given text, as a 2-tuple.
    size = (size[0],size[1]+15)
    im = Image.new('RGBA', size, (0, 0, 0, 0)) # Create a blank image with the given size
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((0, 25), text, font=font, fill=fill) #Draw text
    return im

img = draw_text('zod', 30, (82, 124, 178))
img.save('C:\out.jpg',"JPEG")
print 'Complete!'
os.startfile('C:\out.jpg')
```

I have this bug with other fonts too (tried Arial and Verdana).
help plz :)

Comment: Forgot to say, when I try to draw it lower it only moves the drawn string lower, but the output still misses the top few pixels.

Comment: What's the point of the `size` argument?

Comment: from what I've understood (and I just got face to face with PIL), it's dimensions of the string drawn with given font. In this example it creates the blank image with exact dimensions, so it can fit the string perfectly (or somewhat simulate align: center).
I will need it for centering my string within certain boundaries later on.

I am trying to generate this : http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6908/qttempxd4744.png

and I will need it for each table cell so strings are centered within them.

Comment: I have succeeded!

http://ch1zra.com/d2/runelist.jpg

font.getsize did the trick, and later on it was just a matter of pixel by pixel moving untill I managed to get the X and Y to start from for each row.

also, this one is solved now, but I don't know how to mark it as solved. Maybe to leave answer and then mark it as solved ?

Comment: Yes, although your rep is such that you'll need to wait some time before you can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix this. It appears that drawtext has some issues with certain font sizes.
I've done a bit of experimenting, and it can clearly be seen here that certain font sizes get their top chopped off http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/7677/pilfontsize.jpg

Code for testing above mentioned :

```
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont, Image

im = Image.new('RGBA', (700, 1600), (0, 0, 0, 0)) 
fSize = 1
yVal = 1

while fSize <= 50:
    font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', fSize)
    fString = "This line is in Arial font size " + str(fSize)
    size = font.getsize(fString)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    draw.text((5, yVal), fString, font=font, fill=None)
    fSize += 1
    yVal += fSize + 5
```

Anyhow, I made it, and I'm proud :D
This rendering issue should get worked into by developers of PIL.

Comment: Just for kicks, try a negative font size.

Comment: It crashed my python this morning while I was trying to do it. I got some insane numbers for getsize() values, and the script was unable to proceed.
Can't remember the exact error code I got, but I will reproduce it and post as soon as I get back home from work.

Comment: `(863221, 75359)` this is the getsize tuple I receive for -1 font size (and all other negative font sizes too).  
I also get the following error msg:  
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ch1zra\Desktop\imgGen - Copy.py", line 14, in <module>
    draw.text((5, yVal), fString, font=font, fill=None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 263, in text
    mask, offset = font.getmask2(text, self.fontmode)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 150, in getmask2
    im = fill("L", size, 0)
MemoryError`